# Identify cflag, libs for a make

Tags: compiling, gtk

I'm trying to build a package from sourceforge that made use of GTK2+.  I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 which has GTK4 installed.  I've changed the references to GTK2+ to GTK4.  But I cannot figure out what to use for gdk, glib, and gthread.  Is there a way to list the packages installed? The original makefile had:

GRXLFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0 gdk-2.0 glib-2.0 gthread-2.0`

GRXCFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 gdk-2.0 glib-2.0 gthread-2.0`

After easter-egging around, I determined that

GRXLFLAGS = `pkg-config --libs gtk4`

GRXCFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags gtk4`

would get past make's immediate errors and allow the compiler to run and generate complaints like:

rexxgtk.h:78:20: error: ‘GdkEventKey’ has not been declared
78 |                    GdkEventKey *event,
|                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
rexxgtk.h:81:20: error: ‘GdkEventButton’ has not been declared
81 |                    GdkEventButton *event,

presumably because I hadn't specified the current equivalent of gdk-x.x in cflags. Can someone let me know if there's a general method for finding the names of installed packages.  If not that, can anyone let me know what the appropriate values are for Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: You refer to *changed references from GTK2 to GTK4*, the normal language used is *ported from GTK2 to GTK3* as there is more than just references that need changing (from one library/toolkit version to a later version) with some calls very different (*thus requiring code change*), whilst others may only require recompile.  You gave no specifics as to calls etc, on what appears more a programming question.

Comment: I believe that I can cope with the programming changes required.  I'm sorry that I was unclear in my post:  I'd like a way to determine the appropriate values for the required packages to supply to make.  Ideally a command/program which will list the names of installed gtk, gdk, glib.  Later research indicates the gthread is no longer relevant.